# canvas draw TextView rotation, placement

Tags: android, canvas, textview, draw

I have this code:

```
public class ZeichenView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{
@TargetApi(11)
public final Bitmap getScreenCopy() {
    measure(getWidth(), getHeight());
    layout(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        getWidth(),
        getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        );

    Canvas temporaryCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    bildflaeche.draw(temporaryCanvas);
    messAusgabe.draw(temporaryCanvas);
    referenzAusgabe.draw(temporaryCanvas);
    draw(temporaryCanvas); 

    return bitmap;
}}
```

it draw all elements on one canvas and return one bitmap - but the TextView properties like: rotation and placement is wrong (not) drawed. Why not. The property: text is right.

referenzAusgabe and messAusgabe are TextViews. bildflaeche is a ImageView. I put all on one canvas to have one bitmap after that.

The user changes the rotation and placement of the TextView's so I don't know before where they will be. It would be very nice if you can help me.

Comment: I fail to see a `TextView` here...

Comment: my textViews are: referenzAusgabe and messAusgabe

Comment: Try to use correct variable naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to use:

```
temporaryCanvas.drawtext()
```

and give it the coordinate u want.

also for rotating u can save() -> rotate the canvas -> load()